# Cannot Load Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime after installing Microsoft.AspnetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-assembly, azure-ad-b2c, razor-pages

I have a simple AspNet Core `3.1.1` web application that compiles and runs fine. It's fair to say that aside from custom HTML and CSS this site is an out of the box project created using a Visual Studio template.

The only added nuget package is `BuildWebCompiler  1.12.394` — not quite the latest, though I have tried updating to latest and it doesn't affect the issue that follows.

If I install the nuget package  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI 3.1.1` everything continues to compile fine.  However, I encounter the following exception during `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  HResult=0x80070002
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime, 
  Version=3.1.1.0, 
  Culture=neutral, 
  PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

No code or settings have changed within the project except for the nuget installation. The code that throws the exception is:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddRazorPages(); // <--- throws
   services.AddServerSideBlazor();
}
```

I have poked around and seen this file not found exception is being raised for several assemblies in connection with Core `3.1.x`, but have not found much mention of `Razor.Runtime` specifically.

There is a nuget for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime`, but its version is `2.2.0`. In any case installing this did not seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a known issue. You can trace related threads [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18401) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18334). That is because you updated the NuGet package but haven't installed the 3.1.1 runtime yet.

So you can try below two ways :

- Downgrading `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI` to `3.1.0`
- Using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI` version `3.1.1` but upgrading to [SDK `3.1.101`](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1)

Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18334#issuecomment-581183460

Answer (score 0):

Using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI 3.1.0` seemed to do the trick.

I've yet to look into why.